# JQuery ... how to access smallest key in a dictionary that is greater than a value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying find the smallest value in an array that is larger than an input value.

```
var qty = 6;
var bulkPricing = [
    { max: 5, price: 10.25 },
    { max: 1, price: 11.95 },
    { max: 15, price: 9.25 },
    { max: 35, price: 9.00 },
    { max: 250, price: 8.69 },
    { max: 75, price: 8.87 },
    { max: 125, price: 8.76 },
];
```

How do I find the record that is the smallest value of MAX that is greater than Quantity (in this case the record for Max=15, Price=9.25)

I have ran into `.filter()` but I don't really understand how to use it. Also I need to be pretty backwards compatible with older browsers.

**Updated example code** because it also would need to work for "out of order" items in the array. The items will not always be ordered ascending.

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop and an `if` statement?

Comment: I do know how to use the `for` loop, I am looking for a more elegant solution. I know in C# I would use a LINQ statement, and was looking for something similar in JQuery.

Comment: LINQ is great for these problems indeed, take a look at: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = $(bulkPricing).filter(function(_,el) { 
    return el.max == Math.min.apply(Math, $.map(bulkPricing, function(el) {
        return el.max > qty ? el.max : Infinity
    }));
}).get(0);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9QL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop and an `if` statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bulkPricing.length; i++) {
    if (bulkPricing[i].max > qty) {
        console.log(bulkPricing[i].max, "is bigger than", qty);
        break;
    }
}
```

If the array is not sorted then you can do so like this (*before* running the loop):

```
bulkPricing.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.max - b.max;
});
```

Comment: This only works if the array is already sorted by the `max` key of each object.

Comment: @Asad You are right. I added a snippet for sorting the array.